# How to decrypt PGP encrypted file with Ruby gpgme

Tags: ruby, encryption, gnupg, pgp, gpgme

I can't find a single example of how to do this. I have a PGP encrypted XLS file and a PGP  key. Here's is my code that returns an empty string:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gpgme'

def passfunc(obj, uid_hint, passphrase_info, prev_was_bad, fd)
  io = IO.for_fd(fd, 'w')
  io.puts "PASSPHRASE"
  io.flush
end

encrypted_data = GPGME::Data.new(File.open("file.xls.pgp"))
key = GPGME::Data.new(File.open("key.txt"))

ctx = GPGME::Ctx.new :passphrase_callback => method(:passfunc)
ctx.import_keys key

decrypted = ctx.decrypt encrypted_data

puts decrypted.read
```

I'm able to decrypt this file in a program called GNU Privacy Assistant on Windows using the same key. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Daiki Ueno, the developer of Ruby gpgme reached out to me on GitHub:

> adding `decrypted.seek(0)` after the line `decrypted = ctx.decrypt
>   encrypted_data` seems to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for this. Sometimes I feel like the 'E' of GPGME stands for 'Enigmatic'

Comment: @Vincent what is obj, uid_hint, passphrase_info, prev_was_bad, fd parameters. In my case client has shared public key-private key and encrypted file only

Comment: @Vincent, Please provide your help I'm kind of STUCK! in between.